# java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

My MainActivity.class is invoking putExtra towards SecondActivity.class via setOnClickListener

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sentString", stringName);
startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity.class setOnClickListener

```
//    Recieve the extra sent from MainActivity.class
Intent SecondActivityIntent = getIntent();
String mString = SecondActivityIntent .getExtras().getString("sentString");

//    Send extra to another activity ThirdActivity.class
SecondActivityIntent.putExtra("sentString", mString);
startActivity(SecondActivityIntent);
```

ThirdActivity.class setOnClickListener

```
//    Recieve extra from SecondActivity.class
Intent thirdActivityintent = getIntent();
String mString = thirdActivityintent.getExtra().getString("sentString");
//    This time I am calling SecondActivity.class but I will not send extra
thirdActivityintent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(thirdActivityintent);
```

ThirdActivity.class is causing an

> 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

what does this error mean? Is it because SecondActivity.class is expecting to get an extra from any calling activity? I don't intend to putExtra on ThirdActivity or am I force to. How can this be solve?

Comment: `getIntent().getExtras()` was null... That's all that means

Answer (score 2):

> Is it because SecondActivity.class is expecting to get and extra from any calling activity?

Yes.

> How can this be solve?

Put a default value and a null check

```
//    Receive the extra sent from MainActivity.class
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String mString = "default";

if (extras != null) {
    mString = extras.getString("sentString");
}
```

Comment: Can't apply this because the value of the mString will be provided by the end-user

Comment: The end user is running in an interactive session... The point I am trying to make here is that you have a null or default value when the Intent does not exist

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This will be helpful on my future apps. Yet in my current app, I cannot apply it. finish() does the trick but only if my app goes back 1 step but if I want to back further on the activity stack, finish() won't be able to do it, at least to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Change it into like this
FirstActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sentString", stringName);
startActivity(intent);
```

In SecondActivity

```
//    Recieve the extra sent from MainActivity.class
Intent SecondActivityIntent = getIntent();
String mString = SecondActivityIntent .getStringExtra("sentString");
//    Send extra to another activity ThirdActivity.class
Intent thirdIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
thirdIntent.putExtra("sentString", mString);
startActivity(thirdIntent);
```

The ThirdActivity

```
//    Recieve extra from SecondActivity.class
Intent thirdActivityintent = getIntent();
String mString = thirdActivityintent.getStringExtra("sentString");
//    Just finish Activity
finish();
```

Comment: finish() does work if you want to go back 1 step. How do I use finish() to back 2 or 3 steps?

Comment: start activity for with FLAG CLEAR_TOP or something like this

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.getExtras().getString("sentString");
```

to

```
.getExtras().getString("sentString", "defaultValue");
```

Comment: i cannot apply this because I do not have a default value, the value will be provided by the end-user